# How to let subclass extend methods of the super class in python

Tags: python-2.7, oop

I'm coding the dynamics of a game. There are two kinds of barrier in the game, blocks and balls, which can be pushed. I want balls start to roll when they are being pushed.

So I wrote the following code:

```
class Barrier:
    def __move(self):
        print 'Moving'

    def push(self):
        if self.canMove():
            self.__move()
        else:
            pass # Push barriers in front of it

    def canMove(self):
        return True

class Ball(Barrier):
    def __move(self):
        self.__startRolling()
        super(Ball, self).__move()

    def __startRolling(self):
        print 'Started rolling'

class Block(Barrier):
    # bla bla bla
    pass
```

When `push()` is called, class `Barrier` will check whether it can move(other barriers in front of it can prevent it from moving), and then call `self.__move()`. For class `Ball`, it overrides this method and start rolling before moving.

There are two problems. First, when I ran the following code:

```
ball = Ball()
ball.push()
```

I just got `Moving` on the screen, but no `Started rolling`.

Second, when I ran:

```
ball = Ball()
ball._Ball__move()
```

I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\project\test.py", line 25, in <module>
    ball._Ball__move()
  File "F:\project\test.py", line 15, in __move
    super(Ball, self).__move()
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

How can realize my goal?

Comment: I solved the first problem by changing `def __move` to `def move` in class `Ball`. But I still don't know how to solve the second problem, and I have to  name `move` function in class `Barrier` differently(e.g. `_Barrier__move`) to call it. In this way, I also need to implement `move` function in class `Block`, but I want it just inherit `move` function from class `Barrier`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are running into is due to two leading underscores in `__move()`. This causes name mangling.

In first case your call is dispatched to `Barrier.__move()` instead of `Ball.__move()` because outside the Ball class `Ball.__move()` is only available as `_Ball__move()` which clearly is not being called from `Barrier.push()`.

In second case, I got:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '_Ball__move'
```

Which is again due to name-mangling. `super()` won't have `_Ball__move()` attribute.

To achieve your goal you can remove the two leading underscores.

[PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/): To avoid name clashes with subclasses, use two leading underscores to invoke Python's name mangling rules.

Comment: You have a small typo: `_Ball.__move()`. Extra dot in there. Maybe also worth noting is that if the OP wants to discourage direct calls to the method by code using the classes, they can use a single underscore instead.